# How to export dataTable as Excel format?

Tags: php, jquery, excel, datatables, tabletools

i have used tableTools plugins for Export datatable data, i have included following plugins

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/moment/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/dataTables.tableTools.js"></script>
```

HTML code

```
<table id="result_table" class="display table table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%"></table>
```

and my Initialization part,

```
var oTable = $('#result_table').dataTable({
            //"iDisplayLength": 50,
            //"order" : [[0,"desc"]],
            "columnDefs": [
                { "width": "16%", "targets": 1 }
              ],
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 50, 100, -1], [10, 50, 100, "All"]],
            "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            "tableTools": {
                "sSwfPath": "copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
            }
        });
```

my actuall result is [image]

if i click Excel button my save as window is[image]

it was saved CSV file not as Xls or Xlsx format and also CSV button and Excel Button both are Export CSV file format only.. this is the problem i need to Export Excel format.. pls share your suggestion or solution

Comment: did you searched it properly. go and have look on the following link
https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html
 and 
https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html

Comment: This way i have alreay tried bro, but now i have used tableTools plugin it was also worked correct for example pdf format and copy button csv buttons all are working correct but excel button doesn't export xls format that is the problem.. in your suggestion link does not use tableTools plugin

Comment: you have not added all the js. kindly add the following js also
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js,

//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/pdfmake.min.js,

//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/vfs_fonts.js,

//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js

Comment: after included above plugins doesn't change functionality for Export button

Comment: @RahulSingh, only relevancy if OP wants to use the buttons plugins instead of the retired TableTools, which I think he should too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this approach

```js
oTableTools: {
  sSwfPath: "copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
  aButtons: [
    { sExtends: "xls",
      mColumns: 'visible',
      sFileName: 'export.xls',
      sToolTip: 'Save current table as XLS'
    }
  ]
}
```

The important things is `sExtends: "xls"` and `sFileName` to ensure a proper filename attached to the downloaded file.

But as other people mention in comments, you should really consider using the [**buttons**](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/) plugin, here is a demo using that -> **https://jsfiddle.net/zm825k01/**

Comment: superb sir Thank u so much.. i have one doubt sir tableTools does'nt support xlsx format? i have tried xlsx format but that tell invalid file format

Comment: @BalakumarB, No - I am afraid not. Tabletools xls is basically a specialized css; however the buttons plugin supports `.xlsx`.

Comment: hi sir, how to add custom button to tableTools sir like Docx file format i have to tried this script

Comment: {
 text: 'Docx',
 action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
 alert( 'Button activated' );          }
        }

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did and it worked for me.
Let me know if it helps you.

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script> 
<script src="/js/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/datatables/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/datatables/buttons.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/datatables/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/datatables/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/datatables/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="/js/datatables/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/datatables/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/datatables/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>

var table = $('#example').DataTable({
                lengthChange: false,
                buttons: [ 'copy', 'excel', 'pdf', 'colvis' ]
            });
table.buttons().container().appendTo( '#example_wrapper .col-sm-6:eq(0)' );
```